# method called only one time

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
public void start()
{

if(!isAclone())
{
...
this.thread.start()
}
else
{
...
this.thread.start()
}
```

I would execute one my method inside only `if-block`.wherever I put my method in `start()` method, it is execute twice.how can I achieve this problem?

EDIT

```
private final AtomicBoolean hasRun = new AtomicBoolean();

...
initializeLogger();
if(!hasRun.getAndSet(true))
{
   activateMonitoring();
}

....
```

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382342/call-a-block-of-a-method-only-for-the-first-call-of-the-method

Comment: It is not a duplicate.the situations are different...

Comment: Can you describe please how the situation is different? The answer given there does describe how to ensure a method is run only once. We're not sure what you need done differently, so it's hard to help.

Comment: If you thing about a bit you will see how to use it in your situation

Comment: Why don't you give more details on your scenario. Maybe you should change what you want instead of looking for a narrow solution.

Comment: I do not see how this is different from the duplicate, unfortunately.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I will post the entire code so the thing will be more clearer

Comment: here it is all the class.I would execute activateMonitoring() only one time after initializeLogger() of the if in the start method...the solution give before from Marko Topolnik doesn't work

Comment: @GETah I posted the entire class

Comment: Sorry, but that's a whole lot of code. I still fail to see why you wouldn't be able to adapt my solution, in fact it could be even simpler. Why is `logger` not `static` so you reuse it automatically? And in `initializeLogger` you just check if it's `null` before initializing.

Comment: The code wasn't written by me.it is jigsaw w3c project web server

Comment: Anyway I tried what you say me and it didn't work...

Comment: What exactly have you tried? The code you posted contains zero calls to `activateMonitoring`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In my application httpd thread is executed twice. what I need is that activateMonitoring is called at the second time when httpd thread is executed.So at the first time I don't need activateMonitoring.I need it at the second time.how can I do?

Comment: So you want to execute it **once** and want that once to happen the first time when `isClone == true`? Is that it?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Right...exactly...

Comment: So why don't you insert `activateMonitoring()` at line 2129, and implement the method in the way described in my answer to your previous question? When done and it still doesn't work, paste your attempt at the solution and I'll try to have a look. Be sure to check the CURRENT version of the answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I did what you told me to do but nothing...Unfortunately it didn't worked...

Comment: You don't intend to post the code showing your attempt?

Comment: I posted the code...I edited the post...

Comment: I instructed you to check the CURRENT version of my answer. Please go back to it, refresh the page if needed, and implement it as written. To be more direct: you are missing the `static` modifier on the `AtomicBoolean`. That changes everything.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeeeessssss now it work... static changed everything...you are great...but it is not perfect as I would...I tought that when method start is executed for the second time, it enters to else clause instead at the second time it continue to enter in the if clause. I would execute activateMonitoring at the second time it enter to if clause...how can i do?

Comment: Replace `AtomicBoolean` with `AtomicInteger`, use `getAndIncrement` instead of `getAndSet`, and check for the exact value of 1 or 2, or whatever you make it to be at the second run.

Comment: BTW after all the work I've had with this question, please at least **accept** my answer to the previous question.

Comment: Obviously Marko...you are very nice...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik and user: please add it as an answer and accept, so that we no longer have false "unanswered" question and you both gain rep.

Comment: @jarekczek Out of curiosity... how did you end up at this question, it being of such narrow scope? It would be quite a bit of work to rephrase everything to a final answer, and I don't see enough value in it to do so---except if you make a good case for its value.

Comment: Watching unanswered questions. I thought that copying the part after *EDIT* would be a sufficient answer.